# Java Functional - reversing ANY List type of ANY object

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

I am trying to write a lambda function in Java 8 that will take any type of List of any object. This simple function will reverse a list, the key thing is I want this function to take a list of any object. The function/class is below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

public abstract class ReverseListFunction {

    // function which reverses a list
    public static Function<List<Object>, List<Object>> reverseList = (List<Object> l) ->  {
        int midPoint = endIndex/2;
        for (int i = endIndex; i > midPoint; i-- ) {
            Object temp = l.get(i);
            int distanceFromEndIndex = endIndex - i;
            l.set(i, l.get(distanceFromEndIndex));
            l.set(distanceFromEndIndex, temp);
        }
        return l;
    };

}
```

I've made it static so I can call it without instantiating the class, as below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
            // int i is cast to Integer and added to ints
            ints.add(i);
        }

        // This line prevents compilation
        ints = ReverseListFunction.reverseList.apply(ints);

    }

}
```

The last line in the segment above gives an error stating that apply(List) cannot be applied to argument ArrayList. I was wondering what is the best way to solve this so my function is able to take such an ArrayList of Integers, or indeed any object.

One idea was to use Generics, however I was then unable to use the function from a static context, and when I changed the function to be called on an instance of ReverseListFunction, it still errored as I was providing an ArrayList, not a List.

So, what would be the **functional** way, if it exists, of solving this problem?

Comment: You will need to learn generics so you can use `?` instead of `Object`.  This will make things easier for you.

Comment: I think you need a custom functional `interface Operator { <T> T apply(T x); }` Note the interface itself is non-generic.

Comment: Note that you are modifying the incoming list, so using a `Function` that returns a list is distracting from that fact. This is perfectly demonstrated by your use site `ints = ReverseListFunction.reverseList.apply(ints);` which bears on obsolete assignment. If you implement a `Consumer<List<…>>` instead, the caller understands that there is no result value to assign and immediately comes to the right conclusion that the original list will be modified. As a side effect, it’s possible to declare a function capable of reversing any list, `Consumer<List<?>>`.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: since the incoming list is modified and thus the return value is obsolete, a `Consumer<List<?>>` would be more appropriate and simpler. But in either case, it’s impossible to implement such a function as lambda expression, you’ll need a method reference to a generic method declaration.

Comment: @Holger `Consumer<List<?>>` will have to rely on a wildcard-capturing helper method, it cannot be self-contained. Right?

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: `Consumer<List<?>>` would be the target type of the function, but since lambda expressions can’t declare type parameters, you’ll need a helper method which can. You’ll run into the same issue with the `<T> T apply(T x)` function type; lambda expressions can’t declare type parameters, so you need a method reference.

Comment: @Holger But the lambda expression doesn't have to declare it, it will be inferred at the site where the lambda method is called.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: you can’t infer a type parameter of the functional *method* as that type parameter doesn’t appear in the target type. The target type only contains type parameters of the *class* (functional interface). So if the functional interface’s method is `<T> T apply(T x)`, any attempt to implement it via lambda expression will get a compile error without any ambiguity: “*invalid functional descriptor for lambda expression … method `<T>(T)T` in interface Operator is generic*”…

Comment: @Holger Yes, I didn't expect it would be a type param of the target type, but  it's certainly news to me that the target method can't be generic. I guess the restriction is necessary because it would preclude lambda shape matching.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: the *function* method can’t be generic for a lambda expression, the *target* method (of a method reference) can, so you can implement a generic function method with a method reference to a generic target method. The lambda expression simply lacks a syntax for specifying a type parameter (not introducing such a syntax was a deliberate decision).

Comment: @Holger IntelliJ uses the term "target method" to refer to the method in the target functional type. So you're saying it's just due to syntax, not semantical problems?

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: technically, a lambda expression is a short cut for a method holding the lambda’s body and a method reference pointing to it, so there’s no problem on this side. The problem is to define a syntax that clearly disambiguates between type casts, braced expressions, smaller than, greater-than, minus, and lambda expressions and remains readable. I remember having read a statement regarding that decision, but don’t remember where…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to create a lambda to create the Function object. You can create a static method in your class and use a method reference:

```
public static <T> List<T> reverseList(List<T> l) {
    int endIndex = l.size() - 1;
    int midPoint = endIndex/2;
    for (int i = endIndex; i > midPoint; i-- ) {
        T temp = l.get(i);
        int distanceFromEndIndex = endIndex - i;
        l.set(i, l.get(distanceFromEndIndex));
        l.set(distanceFromEndIndex, temp);
    }
    return l;
}
```

And use the method reference:

```
Function<List<Integer>, List<Integer>> reverseFunction = ReverseListFunction::reverseList;
```

By the way, to reverse a List, there is a method available in `Collections`, you could do:

```
Collections.reverse(myList);
```

Comment: Nice, exactly what I needed as I can keep the class static. I didn't know about declaring generic types just for method. I've made a small amendment to your answer for, as I changed my reverse code